# how to accomplish row selection criteria, per unique id, with pandas groupby calculations?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

## DataFrame group looping alternative?

I have a dataset of 13mil rows with 1,214 stations (unique ids):

```
# copy the data to the clipboard, and read in with
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', index_col=[0])

,tmc_code,measurement_tstamp,travel_time_minutes
0,133-04199,2019-01-01 18:15:00,2.01
1,133-04199,2019-01-01 18:20:00,2.01
2,133-04198,2019-01-01 18:25:00,9.23
3,133-04191,2019-01-01 20:35:00,2.88
4,133-04191,2019-01-01 20:40:00,2.62
5,133-04190,2019-01-01 20:40:00,1.3
6,133-04193,2019-01-01 20:20:00,4.96
7,133-04193,2019-01-01 20:25:00,4.96
8,133-04192,2019-01-01 20:30:00,5.05
9,133-04192,2019-01-01 20:35:00,5.14
10,133-04195,2019-01-01 19:45:00,9.52
11,133-04195,2019-01-01 19:50:00,10.69
12,133-04195,2019-01-01 19:55:00,9.37
13,133-04194,2019-01-01 20:10:00,5.96
14,133-04194,2019-01-01 20:15:00,5.96
15,133-04194,2019-01-01 20:20:00,5.96
16,133P04359,2019-01-01 22:25:00,0.66
17,133P04359,2019-01-01 22:30:00,0.78
18,133P04359,2019-01-01 23:25:00,0.8
19,133P04126,2019-01-01 23:10:00,0.01
20,133P04125,2019-01-01 23:10:00,0.71
21,133+04361,2019-01-01 05:00:00,2.56
22,133+04361,2019-01-01 22:30:00,2.07
23,133+04361,2019-01-01 23:25:00,2.0
24,133+04126,2019-01-01 23:10:00,0.59
25,133+04127,2019-01-01 23:10:00,0.61
26,133+04128,2019-01-01 23:10:00,0.58
27,133+04129,2019-01-01 23:10:00,0.2
28,133+04360,2019-01-01 04:55:00,1.15
29,133+04360,2019-01-01 05:00:00,2.31
```

There are some extreme max values that aren't physically possible, so to trim them out I am trying to use the  **95 percentile plus the mode** to create a threshold and **filter out extreme values**.

Stations produce different values for travel_time (due to length/traffic patterns), so the percentile and mode **must** be by station.

### What I've tried:

```
def feature_cleaner(df, feature, column):
    
    df_feature_group = pd.DataFrame()
    feature_list = list(df[feature].unique())
    for item in feature_list:
        feature_df = df.loc[df[feature]==item]

        feature_df_clean_mode = feature_df.loc[feature_df[column] 
        < (feature_df[column].quantile(.95)
        + feature_df[column].mode().iloc[0])]

        df_feature_group = df_feature_group.append(feature_df_clean_mode)
        
    return df_feature_group
        
df_features = feature_cleaner(df, 'tmc_code', 'travel_time_seconds')
```

this works, but it's very slow.

```
df_clean_tmc = df.groupby(['tmc_code'], as_index=False)['travel_time_seconds'].apply(lambda x: x[x['travel_time_seconds'] 
< (x['travel_time_seconds'].quantile(.95) 
+ x['travel_time_seconds'].apply(lambda x: stats.mode(x)[0]))])
```

I also tried this but it was slow and the result had no calculations performed, it was the same size as the original dataframe.

i suspect the second apply is faulty, but groupby objects have no "mode" function and the stats.mode had worked appropriately in individual groupby tests.

i also tried this:

```
df_clean_tmc = df.groupby(['tmc_code'], as_index=False)
np.where(df_clean_tmc['travel_time_seconds'] 
< (df_clean_tmc['travel_time_seconds'].quantile(.95)
+ df_clean_tmc['travel_time_seconds'].apply(lambda x: stats.mode(x)[0]),df['travel_time_seconds']))
```

But got a type error:

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'DataFrameGroupBy' and 'tuple'`

what would be a more efficient and more appropriate way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the test results, it is unlikely that an improvement of several orders of magnitudes could be achieved (without using bottom-level tools like `numba` or even Cython). This can be seen from the time required to perform the aggregation calculation.

However, two key optimizations could still be made:

- Reduce the number of explicit data passes - mainly the `df[df['col'] = val]` filtering. In my implementation, your for loop is replaced by (1) aggregating everything at once using `.groupby().agg()` and (2) use a lookup table (dict) to check for the threshold. I am not sure if more efficient ways exist, but it would always involve one pass of data, and can only save another few seconds at best.
- Access `df["col"].values` instead of `df["col"]` whenever possible. (N.B. This won't copy the data, as can be easily verified with the `tracemalloc` module turned on.)

**Benchmark Code**:

15M records were generated using your sample.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
# check memory footprint
# import tracemalloc
# tracemalloc.start()

# data
df = pd.read_csv("/mnt/ramdisk/in.csv", index_col="idx")
del df['measurement_tstamp']
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df["travel_time_minutes"] = df["travel_time_minutes"].astype(np.float64)
# repeat
cols = df.columns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 500000, axis=0))
df.columns = cols

# Aggregation starts
t0 = datetime.now()
print(f"Program begins....")

# 1. aggregate everything at once
df_agg = df.groupby("tmc_code").agg(
    mode=("travel_time_minutes", pd.Series.mode),
    q95=("travel_time_minutes", lambda x: np.quantile(x, .95))
)

t1 = datetime.now()
print(f"  Aggregation: {(t1 - t0).total_seconds():.2f}s")

# 2. construct a lookup table for the thresholds
threshold = {}
for tmc_code, row in df_agg.iterrows():  # slow but only 1.2k rows
    threshold[tmc_code] = np.max(row["mode"]) + row["q95"]

t2 = datetime.now()  # doesn't matter
print(f"  Computing Threshold: {(t2 - t1).total_seconds():.2f}s")

# 3. filtering
def f(tmc_code, travel_time_minutes):
    return travel_time_minutes <= threshold[tmc_code]

df = df[list(map(f, df["tmc_code"].values, df["travel_time_minutes"].values))]

t3 = datetime.now()
print(f"  Filter: {(t3 - t2).total_seconds():.2f}s...")
print(f"Program ends in {(datetime.now() - t0).total_seconds():.2f}s")

# memory footprint
# current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
# print(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**6}MB; Peak was {peak / 10**6}MB")
# tracemalloc.stop()

print()
```

**Results**: (3 runs)

```
| No. | old   | new   | new(aggr) | new(filter) |
|-----|-------|-------|-----------|-------------|
| 1   | 24.55 | 14.04 | 9.87      | 4.16        |
| 2   | 23.84 | 13.58 | 9.66      | 3.92        |
| 3   | 24.81 | 14.37 | 10.02     | 4.34        |
| avg | 24.40 | 14.00 |           |             |

=> ~74% faster
```

Tested with python 3.7 and pandas 1.1.2

Comment: This is much much faster, thanks for the input. the result yielded a different amount of row records (~1000). i'm still trying to wrap my head around it entirely, but i'm gonna accept the answer since it 1.) is much faster, 2.) yields comparable results. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! If some stations were not aggregated, you may try aggregating the rows separately to see whether some rows were missing when aggregated together. Or try using different methods such as `np.quantile()` or `scipy.stats.mode()`. And, specifically, check for the singleton stations (i.e. the `tmc_code`'s having only one row or having only missing values). These are generic directions I can tell without looking into the actual data. Success!

Comment: Correction: I mean "aggregating by stations, in separate aggregation functions" above.